# Error Code: 1845. ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported for this operation. Try ALGORITHM=COPY/INPLACE

Tags: mysql, alter-table, mysql-8.0

I upgraded to MySQL 8.0.13 and tried to add a new field using `ALGORITHM=INSTANT` but got the following error:

> Error Code: 1845. ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported for this
>   operation. Try ALGORITHM=COPY/INPLACE

Then I recreated the same table in MySQL 8.0.13 and tried to add the same field using `ALGORITHM=INSTANT` and it works!

Will this new feature of MySQL `(ALGORITHM=INSTANT)` only work on newly created tables in the upgraded version?

Comment: This might be something very specific to the table you are modifying and how it is benign modified. Please include 'SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}' and your 'ALTER TABLE' SQL.

Comment: I tested with several tables even with a small table having a single field but got the same result. I suspect it is a bug.                                               https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92194

Comment: And that bug says "fixed in 8.014".

Comment: Well researched @jithingiri. Feel free to provide this as an answer.  Given 8.0.14 was released a few days ago I suspect you're on an upgrade path. Hope it works for you.

Comment: sure @danblack ..

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, this is a bug

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92194

which is explaining 
 " For ALTER TABLE, ALGORITHM=INSTANT was incorrectly rejected on tables
created in a MySQL version prior to 8.0.12 " 
" Fixed in 8.0.14. "

I didn't tested it with 8.0.14. I will post here the results once I tested it with 8.0.14.

---

[update]

Tested it in 8.0.14 and it works